# ORA-22285 for DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.CLOB2FILE

Tags: json, oracle

I am trying to export  clob data to a json file in Oracle 19c:
*

```
Declare
   Cursor c_emp_files
      is
    SELECT id, clob_data        
    FROM table;        
Begin
   for c in c_emp_files loop
  
    DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.CLOB2FILE(c.clob_data,'c:\temp\','out.json');
    
   end loop;
End;
```

- 

However, it failed with following error:

> ```
> ORA-22285: non-existent directory or file FILEOPEN operation
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 1481 
> ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XSLPROCERSSOR", line 117
> ```

Any suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "flocation" argument to CLOB2FILE is not the name of a directory on your disk - it's the name of a DIRECTORY object in the database. You need to use a `CREATE DIRECTORY` statement to create the DIRECTORY object in the database which "points to" the directory on the disk, and then you can use it (assuming your user has the appropriate permissions).

Note that the directory on disk must be on the machine where the database server is running, so if you're connecting to a remote database you cannot write the data to your local machine. If your database server is running on your local machine you'll be fine.

Also, if your database is running on Oracle v12 or later you should call DBMS_LOB.CLOB2FILE rather than using the deprecated version of CLOB2FILE in XDB.DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.

Comment: It works on the database server with directory object in the database. Thanks Bob!